# How do I save results of a “for” loop into a single variable? (JavaScript ) Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have an Array like this:

```
  var polygons = [
  {
    "_id" : "12345",
    "geometry" : {
       "coordinates" : [[
           [9.123553, 48.71568],
           [ 9.119548, 48.71526 ]
       ]]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id" : "67890",
    "geometry" : {
       "coordinates" : [[
           [ 9.090445, 48.715736 ],
           [ 9.089583, 48.715687 ]
       ]]
    }
  }
]
```

and I need a result like this inside one variable:

```
[
  { 
    "_id" : "12345",
    "coordinates" : [[
      [9.123553, 48.71568],
      [ 9.119548, 48.71526 ]  
    ]]
  },
  { 
    "_id" : "67890",
    "coordinates" : [[
      [ 9.090445, 48.715736 ],
      [ 9.089583, 48.715687 ]  
    ]]
  }
]
```

Up to now I can only console.log the result but I need some advice of how to save the result in one variable.

This is what I got:

```
function printPolygons() {
  for (var i = 0; i < polygons.length; i++) {
    console.log('"polygon_id" : ' + JSON.stringify(polygons[i]._id, null, 4) + ",");
    console.log('"coordinates" : '+ JSON.stringify(polygons[i].geometry.coordinates, null, 4));
  };
};
```

The output looks good in the console but I need to provide it for a REST API endpoint.
Does someone know how to do it?
thanks in regard!

Comment: create an empty array and push you result into that array

Comment: Don't use a `for` loop, use the `.map()` method

Comment: I tried, I didn'T get the right result. One element of the array should be a json object with two key value pairs.

Comment: @Bergi - I also tried that. for some reason it doesn't give me the right result back.
`formatted_polygons = polygons.map(function(polygon){
    return {
      _id : polygon._id,
      coordinates : polygon.geometry.coordinates
    }
});`

and the result looks like this:
 `{ _id: '12345', coordinates: [ [Array] ] },
  { _id: '67890', coordinates: [ [Array] ] }`

Comment: I cannot see whats inside the array. I don't know why

Comment: @1989_lea That looks perfect, exactly what you need? If you are confused about `[Array]`, that's just the way you're logging it as a string. Use `JSON.stringify` to see the complete data.

Comment: @Bergi - `JSON.stringify` worked! I can see the Array now. It doesn't look well formatted, but I can see it now. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```js
const polygons = [
  {
    "_id" : "12345",
    "geometry" : {
       "coordinates" : [[
           [9.123553, 48.71568],
           [ 9.119548, 48.71526 ]
       ]]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id" : "67890",
    "geometry" : {
       "coordinates" : [[
           [ 9.090445, 48.715736 ],
           [ 9.089583, 48.715687 ]
       ]]
    }
  }
];

const result = polygons.map(({ _id, geometry }) => {
    return {
      _id,
      coordinates: geometry.coordinates
    };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var polygons = [{
        "_id": "12345",
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [9.123553, 48.71568],
                    [9.119548, 48.71526]
                ]
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "67890",
        "geometry": {
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [9.090445, 48.715736],
                    [9.089583, 48.715687]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
]

polygons = polygons.map(({
    _id,
    geometry
}) => ({
    _id,
    coordinates: geometry
}));

console.log(polygons);
```